# Why is my output not including spaces when I have an IF statement specifically for it?

Tags: javascript, caesar-cipher

I am trying to make a Caesar's Cipher for a challenge, and there are specific rules I must follow:

- The algorithm uses a numeric "shift" value. You should use a shift of 8 in your code.
- You should IGNORE any characters that are not a letter (this includes symbols such as #*!$^) and they should not be in your output (however a space will remain a space in the encrypted string).
- Your output should take into account both uppercase and lowercase letters. That is, both a lowercase 'a' and uppercase 'A' will have the same shift value.
- Your final answer should be in all capital letters.

JS code:

```
function shift8(string){
  string = string.toUpperCase();
  const alphabetArray = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
  let shiftedString = '';
  
  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    var currentIndex = alphabetArray.indexOf(string[i]);
    var newIndex = currentIndex + 8;
    var currentCharacter = alphabetArray[currentIndex];
    var shiftedCharacter = alphabetArray[newIndex];
    if (currentCharacter == ' ') {
      shiftedString += ' ';
    } else if ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ '.includes(shiftedCharacter)) {
      shiftedString += shiftedCharacter;
    }
  }
  return shiftedString;
}
var output = shift8('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
console.log(output);
```

Is there something I am missing? Is my logic incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alphabetArray.indexOf(string[i])` will return -1 for all values not part of `alphabetArray`, such as spaces. This means that `currentCharacter` will be undefined for any such values.

To fix this, do `var currentCharacter = string[i];` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `currentCharacter` is just a member of `alphabetArray`, which doesn't contain any `' '` (spaces), that's why it's never triggered.

Here, I refactored your code. There is one important thing - you need to loop those indexes, as their max value should be of `alphabetArray.length`.

```js
function shift8(string){
  string = string.toUpperCase();
  const alphabetArray = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA'.split('');
  let shiftedString = '';
  
  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

    let oldCharacter = string[i];
    if( !alphabetArray.includes(oldCharacter) ){

       if( oldCharacter == ' ' ) shiftedString += oldCharacter;

    } else{

       let currentIndex = alphabetArray.indexOf(oldCharacter);
       let newIndex     = (currentIndex + 8) % alphabetArray.length;
       let shiftedCharacter = alphabetArray[newIndex];
       shiftedString += shiftedCharacter;

    }
  }
  return shiftedString;
}
var output = shift8('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

For an space the following will return -1

```
var currentIndex = alphabetArray.indexOf(string[i]);
```

If you should use a shift of 8 in your code alphabetArray doesn't need to have repeated values after the first eight characters in the alphabet because you will never use these values.

The code should be:

```
    function shift8(string){
    string = string.toUpperCase();
    const alphabetArray = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZABCDEFGH'.split('');
    let shiftedString = '';
    
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        const element = string[i]
        if (element == ' ') {
             shiftedString += ' ';
        } else {
            const currentIndex = alphabetArray.indexOf(string[i]);
            if(currentIndex === -1){ // To not include  symbols such as #*!$^
                continue
            }
            const newIndex = currentIndex + 8;
            const currentCharacter = alphabetArray[currentIndex];
            const shiftedCharacter = alphabetArray[newIndex];
            shiftedString += shiftedCharacter
        }  
    }
    return shiftedString;
}
var output = shift8('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog');
console.log(output); // CPM ZDQKS JAXHV NXF RDUYB XEMA CPM TIHG LXO
```